# Why does my phone keep forgetting the Default apps?

Tags: default-applications

Am running CM 7.2 on a Nexus One. Have tried resetting defaults with "Default App Manager," but eventually no matter what I do, my device forgets the Defaults for my Browser, images, music, SMS, etc... Is there a way to fix this permanently?

Answer (score 7):

Normally there're four reasons for default apps to reset.

1. You install an app that can handle that intent.
2. You uninstall an app that can handle that intent.
3. You update an app that can handle that intent.
4. The app is on the sdcard and you rebooted/mounted it on a pc.

The fourth is commonly overlooked. Without source level changes this can't be modified.

Comment: I think that #4 maybe the clue here... The apps in question are all installed on my SD card for space management reasons. I've moved these apps back to the phone and have rebooted. For right now, this appears to have solved the problem. I need to let this sit for a bit before I can claim victory.

Comment: @Kendor So did it solve the problem?